# Listing comment author role code problem

Tags: comments, user-roles

I use the following code on comments template:

```
<?php $user = get_userdata($comment->user_id); 
                echo $user->roles[0];
                ?>
```

But the weird thing is that it is not displaying the comment author role for everyone... just for a few users (even with different roles), and for the rest it is not showing anything.
 Any clue? what am I doing wrong?

thank you!

Comment: Do you allow guest users to comment?

Comment: yes I do. I don't expect to see the role for guests.but even if there are no guest comments on a post, still not showing the role for subscribers or admins. it works only for a few registered users.

Comment: Can you please add some more code like how you are showing this data with comment? Please try by printing the value of `$comment->user_id` so that you can know if that comment has any user associated or not. Also try avoiding `$user` as it may be a global variable, use something like `$user_info`

Comment: the comment has an user associated with it, as other things are working fine. I tried $user_info, but it has exactly the same results. Maybe I should mention that my theme has two comments.php files - one in the theme's directory, and one in theme/functions/comments.php . Not sure if that matters. Maybe I should add a function for this?

Comment: any help, please?

Comment: There is not enough input to find out the real issue. So can you please mention the theme that you are using? Also since there are 2 comments.php files, are you sure in all cases the content is pulled from the file where you have added the above code? Another option will be - switching to default theme and see if this is working or not.